# SQL Server WITH statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My goal is to select result from one CTE and insert into other table with another CTE in the same procedure. How to do it?

My error is...

> invalid object name xy.

My query is

```
WITH ds
(
    Select a, b, c 
    from test1    
),
xy
(
    select d, e, f 
    from test2 
    where (uses conditions from ds)    
)
Select * 
from ds  (the result set of ds, am exporting this to csv)

Insert into AuditTest
(
  Select * from xy
)
```

Comment: i edited my question now. Xy uses conditions from DS. If i use two with statements it is still give me same error.

Comment: A CTE is part of a single SQL statement. The error "invalid object name xy" is from your *second* statement, the INSERT statement, which does not have any CTE defined. (The first statement is the `SELECT`, has two CTEs defined as part of the statement.) To get that second statement to use the CTEs, those will need to be included in the second statement.

Answer (score 26):

A CTE is only good for one query, but it looks like you can use a CTE in each query:

```
WITH ds AS
(
  Select a, b, c from test1    
)
Select * from ds  (the result set of ds, am exporting this to csv)


WITH xy AS
(
 select d,e,f from test2 where (uses conditions from test1)    
)
Insert into AuditTest
(
  Select * from xy
)
```

Answer (score 8):

You actually can do both the insert and output the results using the OUTPUT clause to return the inserted rows.

```
;WITH ds AS
(
  Select a, b, c from test1 
),
xy AS
(
 select d, e, f from test2 where (uses conditions from ds)
)
Insert into AuditTest
output inserted.d, inserted.e, inserted.f
Select d, e, f from xy
```

or a real test

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (a int)

;WITH ds AS
(
  Select 0 as a, 1 as b, 2 as c 
),
xy AS
(
 select a as d, b as e from ds
)
Insert into #Test 
OUTPUT inserted.a
Select e from xy
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run the `INSERT` thusly, you can't run multiple queries after your `cte`:

```
;WITH ds AS (  Select a, b, c 
              from test1    
           )
    ,xy AS (  select d,e,f 
              from test2 
              where (uses conditions from test1)    
           )
Insert into AuditTest
Select * 
from xy
```

In this situation using temporary tables may be beneficial since you'll be re-running a query multiple times otherwise.