# Remove Nulls from Select in a Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a query to total hours week over week by employee. I use a select within a select to separate the weeks into columns. I am receiving Nulls for some employees. How can I remove the Nulls

```
select distinct
EM.EMPLOYEE,
RTRIM(LTRIM(LAST_NAME))+', '+RTRIM(LTRIM(FIRST_NAME)) as [FULL NAME],
(Select SUM(ISNULL(HOURS,'0')) from TimeTbl PT2 WHERE DATEPART(WK, Date) = DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(WK, -1, getdate())) and PAYROLL_YEAR='2020'and PT2.EMPLOYEE=PT.EMPLOYEE) AS [WEEK 1 HOURS],
(Select SUM(ISNULL(HOURS,'0')) from TimeTbl  PT2 WHERE DATEPART(WK, Date) = DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(WK, -2, getdate())) and PAYROLL_YEAR='2020'and PT2.EMPLOYEE=PT.EMPLOYEE) AS [WEEK 2 HOURS],
(Select SUM(ISNULL(HOURS,'0')) from TimeTbl  PT2 WHERE DATEPART(WK, Date) = DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(WK, -3, getdate())) and PAYROLL_YEAR='2020'and PT2.EMPLOYEE=PT.EMPLOYEE) AS [WEEK 3 HOURS],
(Select SUM(ISNULL(HOURS,'0')) from TimeTbl  PT2 WHERE DATEPART(WK, Date) = DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(WK, -4, getdate())) and PAYROLL_YEAR='2020' and PT2.EMPLOYEE=PT.EMPLOYEE)AS [WEEK 4 HOURS],
(Select SUM(ISNULL(HOURS,'0')) from TimeTbl  PT2 WHERE DATEPART(WK, TR_DATE) = DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(WK, -5, getdate())) and PAYROLL_YEAR='2020' and PT2.EMPLOYEE=PT.EMPLOYEE)AS [WEEK 5 HOURS]
From TimeTbl  PT
right join EMPLYTBL EM on PT.EMPLOYEE=EM.EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Considering the use of `ISNULL` and `DISTINCT` this appears to be T-SQL, thus I have removed the MySQL tag. Please don't tag multiple RDBMS unless your query *really* is about multiple RDBMS.

Comment: The sentence 'I am receiving Nulls for some employees' is ambigous ! Can you give more explanation ? An example with some data and your result + expected result would be nice to help you.

Comment: My apologies. This is my first post and it was a suggested tag.

Comment: You can also use a WITH clause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725389/sql-server-with-statement ! Are you sure that for -5 the date used is TR-DATE and not DATE as for other date ?

Comment: It is not important that it is your first post. What is important is that you follow our advice to improve your question. I'm a reviewer (simple user with more than 1500 reputations) and my goal is to help you to improve your question so that StackOverflow remain a quality site.

Comment: It is TR_Date. This is the date column in the DB.  I am trying to group all employees weekly time using TR_Date as the identifier.

Thank you for you help and understanding. I will review my post more carefully from here on out.

Comment: @schlebe Here is the dataset:

EMPLOYEE FULL NAME WEEK 1 HOURS WEEK 2 HOURS WEEK 3 HOURS WEEK 4 HOURS WEEK 5 HOURS
123456 John Smith NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
712345 Jon, Smith NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
812345 Johnny, Smith NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
912345 Bruce, Bruce NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
412346 garcia, vega NULL 8.25 2 1.75 2.75

Thank you for any assistance you are able to provide!

Comment: It is TR-DATE only for week 5 or for all weeks ? If it is for all week, you must adapt your question.

Comment: Can you put this dataset in your question giving some explanation for others users that don't read all comments ? For alignment, I propose that this dataset is formatted as code so you can add space to align columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT EM.EMPLOYEE, RTRIM(LTRIM(LAST_NAME))+', '+RTRIM(LTRIM(FIRST_NAME)) as [FULL NAME],
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WK, Date) = DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(WK, -1, getdate())) and PAYROLL_YEAR = 2020) THEN HOURS END) AS [WEEK 1 HOURS],
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WK, Date) = DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(WK, -2, getdate())) and PAYROLL_YEAR = 2020) THEN HOURS END) AS [WEEK 2 HOURS],
       . . . 
From EMPLYTBL EM left join
     TimeTbl PT
     ON PT.EMPLOYEE = E.EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY EM.EMPLOYEE, RTRIM(LTRIM(LAST_NAME))+', '+RTRIM(LTRIM(FIRST_NAME))
```

Comment: Receive Incorrect Syntax

SUM(DATEPART(WK, DateColumn) = DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(WK, -1, getdate())) and PAYROLL_YEAR = 2020) THEN HOURS END) AS [WEEK 1 HOURS],

Comment: It Should be `Case When ... Then`

ex. 
`SUM(Case when DATEPART(WK, Date) = DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(WK, -1, getdate())) and PAYROLL_YEAR = 2020) THEN HOURS Else 0 END) AS [WEEK 1 HOURS],`